# Dates, Days, Weeks, Difference, Training&shift start formula

Tags: date, google-sheets, datediff

[Data shared in Google sheet found here:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GT3tjBfh3850s4ajkzHFEyCMzuKfHz15fEMsBW1-ymc/edit?usp=sharing)

I am trying to solve a quick issue to calculate the number of training days and working shifts days spent in a small range of calendar week based on a given 'training start date' and the below criteria:

- Weeks are Sunday through Saturday
- Each new agency staff should complete 4 days of training before being planned to work for a max of 6 days in and one calendar week
- When less than 4 training days are completed during the first calendar week, the remaining roll over to the following, immediately followed by working days but not exceeding 6 days of work or training
- To exclude Christmas day
- Calculated from the given date for "Training start' calculate how many training shifts and working shifts for a period of calendar weeks
- Calendar Weeks based on start/finish dates in the "dates' tab

Any advice, feedback or assistance in any way is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you provide example of desired output and all formulae you tried?

Comment: Please provide the formulae you have tried so we can help to identify where you are encountering problems.